Weinberg's derivation of angular momentum eigenvalues
This question comes from S. Weinberg's Lectures on Quantum Mechanics, 2nd ed., pg. 37. At this point, Weinberg has re-written the time-independent Schrodinger equation for a two-body system in a central potential as:
$$
\mathbf{L}^2\psi(\mathbf{x})=\hbar^2\partial_r\left[r^2\partial_r\psi(\mathbf{x})\right]+2\mu r^2\left[E-V(r)\right]\psi(\mathbf{x})
\tag{1}
$$
where $\mu$ is the reduced mass. Weinberg argues that for $V(r)$ not "extremely singular" as $r\rightarrow0$, the wavefunction should have a power series expansion near $r=0$, the dominant contribution to which will be [see also this question]$$
\psi(\mathbf{x})\rightarrow r^\ell\,Y(\theta,\phi)
\tag{2}
$$
where $\ell=0,1,2\dots$. Weinberg then substitutes Eq. (2) into Eq. (1) and takes the $r\rightarrow0$ limit, obtaining
$$
\mathbf{L}^2\psi(\mathbf{x})\rightarrow\hbar^2\ell\left(\ell+1\right)\psi(\mathbf{x})\tag{3}
$$
Therefore, in the limit $r\rightarrow0$, the eigenvalues of $\mathbf{L}^2$ are $\hbar^2\ell\left(\ell+1\right)$. Weinberg then argues the following:

If we choose the wavefunction (as we can) to be an eigenfunction of $\mathbf{L}^2$ as well as of $H$, then according to [Eq. (3)] the eigenvalues can only be $\hbar^2\ell\left(\ell+1\right)$, so [Eq. (3)] must apply not only for $r\rightarrow0$, but for all $r$.

I understand that $\{H,\mathbf{L}^2,L_z\}$ are mutually commuting observables and $\psi(\mathbf{x})$ is therefore an eigenfunction of all three of them. But I don't understand how it is that $\psi(\mathbf{x})$ being an eigenfunction of $H$ suddenly makes Eq. (3) valid for all $r$. Could someone help me understand this argument? Thank you!

Related https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/671535/226902 https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/658433/226902

It is being an eigenfunction of $\mathbf{L}^2$ that implies this.

@PeterKravchuk Just to make sure I'm understanding - are you saying that since $\mathbf{L}^2$ operates only on angles, and not on $r$, that if we can deduce the eigenvalues for any limiting value of $r$, as in Eq. (3), then those eigenvalues must hold for any value of $r$ whatsoever?

No, I'm saying that (3), understood for all r, is simply the eigenvalue/eigenfunction equation for $\mathbf{L}^2$. I.e. literally the meaning of assuming that you have an eigenfunction of $\mathbf{L}^2$. The small r limit is only used to fix the eigenvalue.

@PeterKravchuk I know from the algebra of angular momentum operators that the eigenvalues of $\mathbf{L}^2$ turn out to be $\hbar^2\ell\left(\ell+1\right)$ for all $r$. But Weinberg has only established Eq. (3) by looking at the small $r$ limit. I'm not sure I understand how we can now "understand Eq. (3) for all $r$" and know the eigenvalues are  $\hbar^2\ell\left(\ell+1\right)$ for all $r$.

Weinberg literally says "If we choose the wavefunction (as we can) to be an eigenfunction of $\mathbf{L}^2$". There is no such thing as being an eigenfunction for some $r$ but not other $r$. The eigenvalue cannot depend on $r$. Perhaps you are confused by the concept of an eigenfunction.

@PeterKravchuk Isn't that exactly what I said a few comments ago? That if we can deduce the eigenvalues in the $r\rightarrow0$ limit, then they must hold for all $r$?

No. You said "I'm not sure I understand how we can ... know the eigenvalues are ... for all $r$." Eigenvalues simply cannot depend on $r$ by definition of an eigenfunction. Weinberg assumes (as one can) that you have an eigenfunction. That is how you know.

Ok, I may have misunderstood what you were referring to. In your first comment your tried to make the conclusion that the eigenvalues are $r$-independent based on $\mathbf{L}^2$ not acting on $r$. That is what I disagreed with -- $r$-independence has nothing to do with the specific operator.

Weinberg is initially finding the general wavefunction for the Schrödinger equation written in terms of $\mathbf{L}^2$ that holds for $r\to 0$, call it $\Psi_0$. It's shown that, for reasonable potentials, then
$$\mathbf{L}^2 \Psi_0 = \hbar^2l(l+1)\Psi_0. $$
But this is the eigenvalue equation for $\mathbf{L}^2$, implying it has eigenvalues $\hbar^2 l(l+1)$. Since the eigenvalues of an operator don't depend on the coordinates (at least in this discrete spectrum case), then the operator must have an eigenvalue equation, for any value of $r$
$$\mathbf{L}^2\Psi_l (r,\theta,\phi) = \hbar^2 l(l+1)\Psi_l (r,\theta,\phi), $$
for some (currently unknown) wavefunction $\Psi_l (r,\theta,\phi)$. The "leap" here is finding an eigenvalue equation for $\mathbf{L}^2$ by testing the Schrödinger equation with a $r\to0$ ansatz, that then will hold in general because the eigenvalues don't change.

Discrete spectrum has nothing to do with eigenvalues being coordinate-independent. They are coordinate-independent by the definition.

It's a remark based on the spectrum of the position operator, because, well, the eigenvalues are the positions.
